# Javascript unescape function definition?

Tags: javascript

I've implemented Jint - the javascript engine in C#. The problem is it don't support the depricated `unescape` / `escape` functions, and the alternatives don't return exactly the same result. Same with this implementation: http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/23/escape-unescape-deprecated/

Comment: Why is it a problem that deprecated functions are deprecated?

Comment: Because the ones that should be used instead don't produce exactly the same result. That's in fine most of the time, but, for instance, I'm dealing with some script that hashes god knows what, and using different function/implementation the outputted hash is not what the server expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one replied I had to write the two deprecated `encode` and `decode` functions myself from the Ecma specification. [Standard ECMA-262
5.1 Edition / June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.2). Sorry if those are not written very robust, I'm not a javascript developer.

```
var escape = function (s) {
s = s.toString(s);
var n = s.length;
var result = "";

for(var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    var c = s[k];
    var S = "";
    var code = c.charCodeAt(0);

    if(("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./").indexOf(c) > -1) {
        S = c;
    }
    else if(code < 256) {
        S = '%' + code.toString(16);
    }
    else {
        S = code.toString(16);
        S = "%u" + ("0000").substring(0, 4 - S.length) + S; 
    }
    result = result + S;
}
return result;};
```

.

```
var unescape = function (s) {
s = s.toString(s);
var n = s.length;
var result = "";

for(var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    var c = s[k];
    if(c == '%') {
        if(k <= (n - 6)) {
            if(s[k + 1] == 'u') {
                if(("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 2]) > -1 &&
                   ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 3]) > -1 &&
                   ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 4]) > -1 &&
                   ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 5]) > -1) {
                        c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(s.substring(k + 2, k + 7), 16));
                        k = k + 5;
                   }
                   else {
                        if(k <= (n - 3) && 
                        ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 1]) > -1 && 
                        ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 2]) > -1)
                        {
                            c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(("00" + s.substring(k + 1, k + 3)), 16));
                            k = k + 2;
                        }
                   }
            }
            else {
                if(k <= (n - 3) && 
                  ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 1]) > -1 && 
                  ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 2]) > -1) {
                    c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(("00" + s.substring(k + 1, k + 3)), 16));
                    k = k + 2;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 1]) > -1 &&
                ("0123456789abcdef").indexOf(s[k + 2]) > -1) {
            c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(("00" + s.substring(k + 1, k + 3)), 16));
            k = k + 2;
        }
    }
    result = result + c;
}

return result;};
```

Answer (score 1):

Polyfill of `unescape` from [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-string-and-regexp):

> In web development, a *polyfill* is code that implements a feature on web browsers that do not support the feature. Most often, it refers to a JavaScript library that implements an HTML5 or CSS web standard, either an established standard (supported by some browsers) on older browsers, or a proposed standard (not supported by any browsers) on existing browsers. Formally, "a polyfill is a shim for a browser API".

```js
'use strict';
var $ = require('../internals/export');
var uncurryThis = require('../internals/function-uncurry-this');
var toString = require('../internals/to-string');

var fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
var charAt = uncurryThis(''.charAt);
var exec = uncurryThis(/./.exec);
var stringSlice = uncurryThis(''.slice);

var hex2 = /^[\da-f]{2}$/i;
var hex4 = /^[\da-f]{4}$/i;

// `unescape` method
// https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unescape-string
$({ global: true }, {
  unescape: function unescape(string) {
    var str = toString(string);
    var result = '';
    var length = str.length;
    var index = 0;
    var chr, part;
    while (index < length) {
      chr = charAt(str, index++);
      if (chr === '%') {
        if (charAt(str, index) === 'u') {
          part = stringSlice(str, index + 1, index + 5);
          if (exec(hex4, part)) {
            result += fromCharCode(parseInt(part, 16));
            index += 5;
            continue;
          }
        } else {
          part = stringSlice(str, index, index + 2);
          if (exec(hex2, part)) {
            result += fromCharCode(parseInt(part, 16));
            index += 2;
            continue;
          }
        }
      }
      result += chr;
    } return result;
  }
});
```

Explanation from [ECMAScript Language Specification # sec-unescape-string](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers.html#sec-unescape-string):

[image: unescape explanation]